# How to disable column in GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, devexpress, datagridviewcolumn

I'd like to disable column in DevExpress [detailView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.class) in [GridView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.class). For now I can hide columns in this view by following code but I cannot make those columns readonly or not enabled:

```
private void GridView_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, CustomMasterRowEventsArgs e)
{
    var masterView = sender as GridView;
    GridView detailView = masterView?.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex) as GridView;
    detailView?.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void GridView_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, CustomMasterRowEventsArgs e)
{
    var masterView = sender as GridView;
    GridView detailView = masterView?.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex) as GridView;

    //Make the column read-only
    detailView?.Columns[0].OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;

    //Make the column non-editable
    detailView?.Columns[0].OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
}
```

Documentation:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly.property

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit.property